# activity relaunch issue when the Home key is pressed

Tags: android

My scenario:

- i have 3 activities. from Activity 2 - Activity 3 ...On Activity3  i press home key
- Then from Filemanager app, i have a zip file which i need to import. When click on the zip file, my app launches and imports the device list in Activity 1.
- Then i go to Activity 2 - Activity 3.
- From Activity 3 i press back key.  it takes me to Activity 2.  I press back key again (it should quit my app from activity 2). But instead It takes me to Activity 3 again.  From there I am stuck as no response when pressing back key.

I assume that since i press Home button first time. the activity 3 is in back ground.  Then when i launch the app from another app ..i think 2 instances had been created.

I really dont know how to solve this issue.

I want the back key function as :

Activity 3 - back key - Activity 2 - back key - quit the app

Answer (score 0):

Use launch mode as FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP for Activity3

check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that since i press Home button first time. the activity 3 is
>   in back ground. Then when i launch the app from another app ..i think
>   2 instances had been created.

You are right, by default in `Android` if you do not set any flag for `activity`, you will able to create `multiple instances` for `activity`. In your case, you have multi `instances` of `activity` 2 and 3.

To reach what you want, I recommend as below.

From `activity 1,` when you call `start` `activity 2`, try to add line of code below to the `intent` to clear the `backstack` of `activity`.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```